# Conditional Formatting Formula comparing todays month with certain months

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

So I have been trying to format this conditional formatting for a while but I am having trouble writing my Or and AND Statements in the IF statement

These are the rules:

**Conditional formatting = Green:**

If (today's month = January OR April OR July OR October) AND G6>31%

[image]

OR If (today's month = February OR May OR August OR November) AND G6>63%

OR If (today's month = March OR June OR September OR December) AND G6>98%

**Conditional formatting is Red:**

If none of green conditions are fulfilled

This was the best I could come up with before getting lost on how to write it

```
=If((And($G$6>31%;OR((Month(Now())=Month("01-Jan-2022");(Month(Now())=Month("01-Apr-2022");(Month(Now())=Month("01-Jul-2022");(Month(Now())=Month("01-Oct-2022"))))))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Use this for **GREEN** --> `=OR(AND(G6>0.31,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-1-22"),MONTH("1-4-22"),MONTH("1-7-22"),MONTH("1-10-22"))),AND(G6>0.63,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-2-22"),MONTH("1-5-22"),MONTH("1-8-22"),MONTH("1-11-22"))),AND(G6>0.98,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-3-22"),MONTH("1-6-22"),MONTH("1-9-22"),MONTH("1-12-22"))))=TRUE` , while for **RED** just change the `TRUE` to `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but it's telling me that there's a problem with the formula :{

Comment: Yes, that's because you need to change the comma's to semicolon ;

Comment: I did that but it didn't work

Comment: Show screenshot, where it is not working for you, because it worked for me

Comment: I edited the post and uploaded the screenshot

Comment: =OR(AND(G6>0.31;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-1-22");MONTH("1-4-22");MONTH("1-7-22");MONTH("1-10-22")));AND(G6>0.63;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-2-22");MONTH("1-5-22");MONTH("1-8-22");MONTH("1-11-22")));AND(G6>0.98;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-3-22");MONTH("1-6-22");MONTH("1-9-22");MONTH("1-12-22"))))=TRUE

Comment: That screenshot shows you have not entered the formula, in this manner, `6>0.31;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-1-22");MONTH("1-4-22");MONTH("1-7-22");MONTH("1-10-22")));AND(G6>0.63;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-2-22");MONTH("1-5-22");MONTH("1-8-22");MONTH("1-11-22")));AND(G6>0.98;OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-3-22");MONTH("1-6-22");MONTH("1-9-22");MONTH("1-12-22"))))=TRUE`

Comment: And the error pop is self explanatory, are you sure, that it is not working, because i have checked and checked that it is working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243705/discussion-between-ysws-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check image below, its working as I have commented above,

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]

• For `TRUE` --> **GREEN**

```
=OR(AND(G6>0.31,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-1-22"),MONTH("1-4-22"),MONTH("1-7-22"),MONTH("1-10-22"))),
AND(G6>0.63,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-2-22"),MONTH("1-5-22"),MONTH("1-8-22"),MONTH("1-11-22"))),
AND(G6>0.98,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-3-22"),MONTH("1-6-22"),MONTH("1-9-22"),MONTH("1-12-22"))))=TRUE
```

• For `FALSE` --> **RED**

```
=OR(AND(G6>0.31,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-1-22"),MONTH("1-4-22"),MONTH("1-7-22"),MONTH("1-10-22"))),
AND(G6>0.63,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-2-22"),MONTH("1-5-22"),MONTH("1-8-22"),MONTH("1-11-22"))),
AND(G6>0.98,OR(MONTH(TODAY())=MONTH("1-3-22"),MONTH("1-6-22"),MONTH("1-9-22"),MONTH("1-12-22"))))=FALSE
```

[image: CONDITONAL_FORMATTING]